# Is there a better way of getting elements with x,y coordinates from a numpy array?

Tags: performance, numpy, indexing

It is possible to index a numpy array with a tuple of sequences such that `tpl[0]` is a a sequence of *x* coordinates and `tple[1]` is a sequence of *y* coordinates.  One simply needs to index the array with the tuple, thus:  `other_array[tpl]`.

I currently have coordinates stored in a 2D array such that the vector `ar[0]` corresponds to my *x* values and `ar[1]` corresponds to my *y* values.

Right now, I'm indexing `other_array` by creating a tuple:  `other_array((ar[0], ar[1]))`.  Unfortunately, this operation is running in a tight loop, so any amount of performance I can squeeze out would be highly beneficial.  Creating a tuple can add a bit of overhead if performed 10^8 times!  Is there a faster, numpythonic way of indexing with such a matrix of *xy* coordinates?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I wonder if there might be better ways to optimize your tight loop - operating on an entire array in some way is usually much faster than one element at a time. Perhaps showing your inner loop and explaining what it does will get you a bigger gain...

Comment: @Floris, Indeed I'm making an effort to operate on arrays using logical indexing rather than with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index a numpy array with another array, so you don't have to create a tuple.  For example:

```
In [199]: other_array
Out[199]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

In [200]: ar
Out[200]: 
array([[0, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 0]])

In [201]: other_array[ar[0], ar[1]]
Out[201]: array([ 1, 13,  5])
```

If that doesn't answer your question, could you include a simple working example in your question that shows what you are currently doing?

Comment: While you are not explicitly creating a tuple, what `other_array.__getitem__` receives as argument is the tuple `(ar[0], ar[1])`, so a tuple is created anyway. It doesn't matter much, because the OP's concerns about creating a two element tuple are unwarranted: even if each element is an array with a gazillion elements, the tuple is made up of only two pointers.